# Automated task to see deprecated functions used in a site

Tags: 8

There have already been many [Drupal 8 functions that have been deprecated](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/deprecated).

Is there an automated way (perhaps through the reporting pages in Drupal or a code linter) that reports when these deprecated functions/methods are used from code used from the site?

The goal, of course, is to stay as current as possible on our APIs so that we're ready when Drupal 9 drops.

Comment: Using an IDE like PHPStorm will tell you what functions or methods are deprecated.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134303/phpstorm-find-all-deprecated-usages-in-the-project

Comment: Thanks, but is there an automated way to do this without relying on a specific IDE? Through a module or code linting?

Comment: Any IDE should be able to do this.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being specific enough. I would like to automate this process so the deprecated functions are not overlooked. If they were built into a linting process or perhaps reported through Drupal UI, they could be worked into the production cycle and fixed as they come up. Developers shouldn't need to do manual checks on hundreds of files to see if we're using deprecated API calls.

Comment: No one said it is manual - in PHPStorm you literally hit Code > Run Inspection by Name and type in "Deprecated". It scans the entire project or parts of a project for deprecated code, and presents the results to you, what and where. I am almost certain NetBeans or Eclipse or others can also do this.

Comment: That is still manual. Automated would mean code could not commit with deprecated functions, or that deprecated functions be presented in the reporting pages and impossible to ignore. I think manual scans is an okay technique while finding deprecated calls but in this case, we'd like to always know what deprecated code we're using without manually checking.

Comment: @TimWasson Found this article using [phpstan](https://glamanate.com/blog/testing-your-drupal-code-base-deprecated-code-usage-phpstan) on Planet Drupal